# ResourceBundle does not correspond to the requested locale

Tags: java, internationalization, locale, resourcebundle

The instantiated resourceBundle does not correspond to the requestd locale(zh_TW). As a result strings from the fallback messages.properties are  being picked. What am I missing?

This doesn't happen with locale which contain no underscores(Ex : es, pl, fr etc)

```
Locale myLocale = new Locale("zh_TW");
ResourceBundle resourceBundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("messages", myLocale);
System.out.println("ResourceBundle locale : " + resourceBundle.getLocale());
```

Output

> Default locale : en_US
>   ResourceBundle locale :

Answer (score 1):

Also note that when ResourceBundle.getBundle() parses the properties file and finds an invalid character, it fails silently and falls back on the default properties file.

Answer (score 0):

The Locale class provides three constructors:

```
 Locale(String language)
 Locale(String language, String country)
 Locale(String language, String country, String variant)
```

You most probably need to do:

```
Locale myLocale = new Locale("zh", "TW");
```

Comment: 'TW' is not the country code for china. 'cn' is. zh_TW is traditional chinese, a variant.

Comment: @AbhijithMadhav zh_TW is Chinese in Taiwan and is definitely not a variant. TW is the country code. you can (usually) assume that it is traditional, but if you are trying to do Traditional Chinese in another country you need to use zh-Hant-TW (replacing TW with the appropriate country) with `Locale.forLanguageTag(String languageTag)` (if java 7 or above)